# MySQL Copying table data with on duplicate key update using INSERT... "field id is ambiguous?"

Tags: mysql, insert, copy, key, duplicates

Im trying to copy contents from one table to another, both having identical table structure.

```
INSERT INTO master SELECT * FROM slave
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id+1
```

This gives the error:
`#1052 - Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`

Seems like a simple problem but I can't resolve it. Does anyone know hot to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it says is the exact problem: `Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous`. You have to specify which `id` column you mean -- the `master`'s or the `slave`'s. You specify the `master`'s `id` column by putting a dot between the table name and field name, `master.id`:

```
INSERT INTO master SELECT * FROM slave
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE master.id = master.id + 1
```

Comment: Hello and thank you. I have just tried this and now it returns `#1062 - Duplicate entry '117' for key 'PRIMARY'`. So if an ID already exists that is one integer higher, than this fails or is there a way around it?

Comment: Then your duplicate key update of statementing the id is not going to work, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: @user1093634, how you get around it really depends on your specific data.